# How to Call java web service from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

When i call java web service from asp.net. it shows error

```
java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception.
```

My code :

```
WebReference Rs = new WebReference();
string GetXMl = Rs.getPosition("dd/mm/yyyy", "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Comment: too broad. put a bit of the code to narrow down your problem.

Comment: @Nandha What kind of web service is yours? RPC, SOAP, REST.... How you send/receive data? XML, JSON...?

Comment: I am using Soap and return type is XML

Comment: do you have wsdl for web service?

Answer (score 0):

You must instanciate your proxy class, but not your server class

you can follow these steps

1 Go to Solution Explorer window.

2 Right click on the project. A context menu pops up.

3 Click the Add Web Reference menu. The Add Web Reference dialog opens.

4 Copy and paste the WSDL URL from our web brower’s address bar  to Add Web Reference dialog’s address bar and press go button .

We can see all the methods names of our web service.

5 using yourNamespace;

6 Next, create the object of the web reference.

```
yourTypeProxy proxy = new yourTypeProxy();
```